# how to use fuel asynchronously in a kotlin jvm console app

Tags: kotlin, jvm

I'm trying to use Fuel library to call some web-services asynchronously but the application process exits before the processing finishes.
Using `sleep` to delay exit is dumb, but I could not find a better way. Most of the examples show Fuel usage in a servlet or an android app.

Here is a sample.I used reqres to simulate a long-running service call.

```
    import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.core.FuelManager
    import com.github.kittinunf.fuel.httpGet

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        FuelManager.instance.baseHeaders = mapOf(
                "User-Agent" to "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0"
        )

        "https://reqres.in/api/users?delay=3".httpGet().responseString { _, _, result ->
            result.fold(
                    { str ->
                        println("success")
                    },
                    { fuelError ->
                        println("got error: $fuelError")
                    })
        }
        Thread.sleep(5_000)
        println("main finishes")
    }
```

Should I look into coroutines-style usage of Fuel or there is an easier way?

Comment: Maybe you should rethink your solution, if all your application does is make an api call is there need to use asynchronous approach? Asynchronous programming is usually used to perform some action that might take a while without blocking main flow of your application. So logically if your application exits before that action is done there is no need for result.

Comment: It is indeed possible to rewrite the app in blocking way without lambdas. But in the real case some heavy recursive processing is involved and functional-style fuel code is so much more understandable.

Comment: As I said if you start asynchronous computation but your application exits before that computation finish there is no need for result, for example lets say you open some website, which uses async API call to get list of some data, if you exit before data is received there is no need for it, same happens in your case, you do nothing after async call, so application simply quits, in other to avoid that you need to introduce blocking call somewhere, in other to make it wait for async operation to finish.

Comment: Just throw up a "Press CTRL-C to quit..." message on System.out and block the main thread with `System.in.read()` if you want to use async code. When you're done just quit your program with `System.exit()`.